# Solve a recursive equation about chess

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion, chessboard

If we know that the King stands in the square on the left side at the bottom and has each time 3 possible moves:

```
he goes 1 square to right
he goes 1 square up
he moves diagonally to the right
```

so if he start from the square f(1,1) then to know how many possibilities there are to get to square f(m,n) then we can use this equation :
$$
 f(m,n)=f(m-1,n-1)+f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)
$$
The question is how to prove that this equation down is a solution of equation for $f(n,n)$ :
 $$
 f(n, n) =\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose i} {n-1+i \choose i}
$$

Comment: There also is a solution given as $f(m,n) = \left(\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)^m b^n$ for any $b \ne 1$

Comment: So ... $f(n,m)$ is how many possibilities there are to go from the square $(1,1)$ to $(n,m)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start for convenience only with $f(0,0)=1$ instead of $f(1,1)=1$ and with boundary conditions $f(m,0)=f(0,n)=1$ with integral $m,n\geq 0$. Since each step of length $1$ can be encoded with $$x+xy+y$$ we obtain the generating function
\begin{align*}
F(x,y)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(m,n)x^my^n\tag{0}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(x+xy+y)^j\\
&=\frac{1}{1-(x+xy+y)}
\end{align*}

> We calculate $f(n,n)=[x^ny^n]F(x,y)$ with $n\geq 0$ by noting that we can take $n$ up to $2n$ steps in order to go from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(n,n)}&=\sum_{j=n}^{2n}[x^ny^n](x+xy+y)^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=n}^{2n}[x^ny^n]\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}x^l(1+y)^ly^{j-l}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=n}^{2n}[y^n]\binom{j}{n}(1+y)^ny^{j-n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=n}^{2n}\binom{j}{n}[y^{2n-j}](1+y)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+j}{n}[y^{n-j}](1+y)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{n+j}{n}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows since starting with $f(1,1)=1$ means reducing the path length by one which is replacing $n$ with $n-1$ in (6).

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theroem to $(x(1+y)+y)^j$.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^n$.
- In (3) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we shift the index to start with $j=0$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $y^{n-j}$.
- In (6) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

> *Note:* The numbers $f(n,n)$ are the *[Central Delannoy numbers](https://oeis.org/A001850)* archived in OEIS.

**Add-on:** We can derive the generating function $F(x,y)$ from the recurrence relation in a somewhat more detailed manner as follows.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n)x^my^n&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m-1,n-1)x^my^n
> +\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m-1,n)x^my^n\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(m,n-1)x^my^n\\
> &=xy\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(m,n)x^my^n+x\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty  f(m,n)x^my^n\\
> &\qquad+y\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(m,n)x^my^n\\
> F(x,y)-\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-y}+1&=xyF(x,y)+x\left(F(x,y)-\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
> &\qquad+y\left(F(x,y)-\frac{1}{1-y}\right)\\
> F(x,y)&=\frac{1}{1-x-y-xy}
> \end{align*}

Comment: can  u please tell me how did u create the generating function :
                F(x,y)=∑m=0∞∑n=0∞f(m,n)xmyn

Comment: @AshrafBeshtawi: The method to encode a sequence $f(m,n)$ with it's generating function $F(x,y)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(m,n) x^my^n$ is a common technique. You might want to check *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)* by H. S. Wilf which provides valuable information regarding this approach.